# not able to post nested object to strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have created a collection and inside the collection I have linked 3 more collections using relations like so:
[image]

But I am unable to add data to the collection through api calls.

Data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Material": "abcd",
        "sizes": [
            {
                "size": "size-1"
            },
            {
                "size": "size-2"
            }
        ],
        "slabs_numbers": [
            {
                "size": "xxx",
                "quantity": 10
            }
        ],
        "slabs_series": [
            {
                "series": "series-1"
            },
            {
                "series": "series-2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I got an error like this:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Undefined attribute level operator size",
        "details": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "path": [],
                    "message": "Undefined attribute level operator size",
                    "name": "ValidationError"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a product with all new data of sizes, slabs_numbers and slabs_series but I am getting the above error.

I want the data to be uploaded to the parent collection `product_slabs` and all the relative collections which are sizes, slabs_series etc...

Comment: Can you add the request you're making please?